# Is it possible to automatically reload the app in react native?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to have a react native app to automatically reload in the emulator once I edit the sources and the thing recompiles itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933287/how-to-enable-live-reload-in-react-native-on-android/42571633#42571633

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you've created your project with `react-native init`, then on the simulator, press `cmd+ctrl+Z` or `Hardware > Shake Gesture` and the Dev Menu will popup.

Just press `Enable Live Reload` and Done! :D

**EDIT :** 
React Native team does now encourage to user **Hot Reloading** instead of **Live Reload**. More info about [the difference between those two features here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading.html).

Comment: Is there a way of enabling this by default, all the time?

Comment: hm, i don't have this option now. I had it before

Comment: @Toolkit I think they moved it, now you have to go to the Dev Menu > Dev Settings and check "Auto reload on JS change"

Comment: Dev Menu in on device doesn't have this item

Comment: Is there a way to have this feature also when running the app on device ? I don't see that option in the dev menu.

Comment: Is there any ADB command that you can send to the device to reload? I don't like Hot reloading !!

Answer (score 3):

You can use hot-reload in the settings for your react native app to automatically reload. you can enable hot-reloading click the "Menu" button on the sidebar inside genymotion.

Answer (score 2):

Hot Module Reloading (HMR) shipped with [RN 0.22](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.22.0) a few days ago, which lets the simulator automatically reload a single screen or other module without reloading the entire app.  It's enabled via the same CMD+D / CMD+CTRL+Z / Shake Gesture menu.

Comment: Good answer, keep it simple just press CMD + D on from your simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge workaround – but it is saving a lot of time and avoiding the frustration of not shaking correctly.

Also it covers the edge case of complete reloading the bundle, not only for live reloading or hot replacement.

We just `throw new Error('Want to refresh?')` to prompt the error screen while in development, so we can hit `RELOAD` on the bottom.

Beware of the dragons. This is not the most usual move.

Answer (score 0):

use this command from the shell

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

to get dev menu on android real device.