# React native run-android do not updating modified code

Tags: android, npm, react-native

I am using React native 0.52.0 and react-native-cli 2.0.1 on my Windows PC for android development. Despite all the changes i have made. When I run `react-native run-android`, it builds successfully but when I run it, I get the default react native screen.

The result when I run `react-native run-android`-
[image]

The app I get-

[image]

**index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactNative, { Text } from 'react-native'

export default const App = () => {
  return (
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
  )
}
```

When i ran `react-native init albums`, it was just an index.js file that was created, there was no index.android.js or index.ios.js file
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you need to study it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933287/how-to-enable-live-reload-in-react-native-on-android/42571633

Answer (score 61):

Assuming that you are in the right folder, try to do this:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

if you have index.android.js, do this instead:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Then just execute  react-native run-android.

Comment: I did as you said, this is the error message i got                          FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'albums'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle
-3.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle
-3.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :

Comment: After running, the first line of code you said, my Build is failing

Comment: Ensure that the paths are in the command are the same as you have in the project.

Comment: No, you shouldn't.

Comment: It seems I must use from `sudo ` in ubuntu

Comment: It's strange that you should to use sudo but, I own a react native project that don't let me modify Android Manifest unless I would open with sudo mode and I still don't know why xD

Comment: In my case, it needs to run everytime. Anyone has solution?

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: Any permanent solution for this? If anyone has found one. please let me know.
It would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 37):

**SOLUTION**

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

OUTPUT will be :

```
`c:\Users\lenger\Desktop\webrowser>react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
Scanning folders for symlinks in c:\Users\lenger\Desktop\webrowser\node_modules (43ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in c:\Users\lenger\Desktop\webrowser\node_modules (38ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
```

and after

Run `react-native run-android` again, you will find your modification work.

https://lengerrong.blogspot.am/2018/01/react-native-run-android-do-not.html

Comment: It seems that this command should be run every time before building?

Comment: @fujianjin6471 didyou get any solution? Or i need to run everytime?

Comment: @BhaveshHirpara Up to now it is

Comment: Thanks +1. Currently I am running in iOS and at end of development i just test in android so that i can avoid executing command multiple time

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.
Step 1)

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman
```

Step2)

```
react-native start
```

Comment: I got the error message after first command.
[watchman] while computing sockname: failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/USERNAME-state: No such file or directory

Comment: I got the answer from the link. https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/760 \n sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/run/watchman \n
sudo chmod 2777 /usr/local/var/run/watchman

Answer (score 5):

**Open package.json file and update this code.**

```
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios"
},
```

**Assuming that you are in the right folder, try to do this:**

Run this command only it will automatically both commands.

`npm run android`

Comment: this is bad for every time app run

Answer (score 4):

in your terminal window go to your project folder and than try this command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Answer (score 4):

This [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21135#issuecomment-508078773) on github fixed my problem.

> @neonsec Cool, it do works !
>
> and I find a reason why this happened
>
> https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/4b98623e8fde17588f27494f3ae8f084b9b227d3/QueryableView.cpp#L48
>
> it looks like when a .git/index.lock or a .hg/wlock file exist, watchman will do nothing

**Solution**: **DELETE** `.git/index.lock` file

```sh
## root app dir
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

otherlink:
https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/4b98623e8fde17588f27494f3ae8f084b9b227d3/QueryableView.cpp#L48

Answer (score 3):

You are probably updating the wrong file and not calling it in the AppRegistry class.

Check (or post) your full index.android.js and make sure that the file that it is invoking and importing is the one you are actually modifying.

Answer (score 3):

Run the script:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

After that, just do:

```
$ gradlew clean
$ react-native link
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

In your project folder run this

```
c:\Users\lenger\Desktop\YourProjectFolder>react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Scanning folders for symlinks in c:

```
\Users\lenger\Desktop\webrowser\node_modules (43ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in c:\Users\lenger\Desktop\webrowser\node_modules (38ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
```

Run react-native run-android again

I share the link where i found this solution:
https://lengerrong.blogspot.com/2018/01/react-native-run-android-do-not.html

Comment: but, do I need to write bundle everytime, while running?

Answer (score 2):

### For CodePush users

I was having this same problem but it didn't update my code just on a production build, it works fine in development.

My problem was CodePush, it was updating my app because it had the same version than the last CodePush release target version and it was a mandatory update (I didn't change the version target because it was just for testing purpose), then, I commented the CodePush code on my App.js and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

After trying @SmoggeR_js answer and still if you have the same problem try following
(Assuming that you have created keys and already signed the apk)

1. Delete `build` inside `android/app` folder
2. Delete `build` inside `android` folder
3. run `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/` to delete cache
4. Open `build.gradle` --> `android/app/build.gradle`
5. comment out this line
   `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`
6. Delete `index.android.bundle` file from `assets` folder `( android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle)`
7. run following command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
8. `react-native run-android --variant=release` (you have to generate signed keys and all the keys should updated in the gradle file ref (https://s-pace.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, deleting below line in gradle.properties solved it.

*org.gradle.configureondemand = true*

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I had removed internet permissions from my AndroidManifest.xml (since it technically wasn't needed). React Native uses that permission to connect your app to the development machine (and enable live-debugging).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your Android Studio -> "**Tools**" menu -> "**AVD manager**" and right click the emulator you are using, choose "**Wipe Data**" then "**Cold Boot Now**" should solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **index.android.js** then follow the following steps:

Delete **index.android.bundle** within **android/app/src/main/assets** and then -

1. *react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/*
2. *cd ./android*
3. *./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets*

Answer (score 1):

**Fix it in 3 steps:**

1. Enable Live Reload
2. Disable Hot Reloading
3. In Dev Settings, uncheck JS Dev Mode

Now your app automatically updating everytime you made changes to your codes.

Comment: I thought it was a bug and forget that you need to re-enable the live reload and hot reload every time you clone it onto a new system

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cd .git (in your react-native folder)
rm index.lock
```

and restart metro bundler i.e. `react-native start`

wallaa!!...

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, there is package.json file. You can add following code snippet in that json file under scripts:. After that you can run application using one command that is `npm run android-windows`. To work fine you should add below code script.

```
"android-windows": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"
```

[image]

Comment: Do we have to run everytime in order to see modification of the code?

Answer (score 0):

> there was no index.android.js or index.ios.js file

In this case you have to follow the instructions on your mobile/emulator as below:

[image]

After saved your `App.js`, remember to type twice `R` in uppercase

For make it automatically changes, on Android emulator press `CTRL + M` (`CMD + M` on MacOS) or shake the Android device which has the running app and select `Hot reloading` (keep current state, change only the file you have changed) or `Live reloading` (reload the entire app).

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake by me that not to save edits of App.js. After Saving data will reflect :)

Comment: Hi, Currently answer looks more like comment, you will be able to add comment when have 50+ reps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I disable debugging then it updates.
So this is my solution.

in Chrome dev tools > Network > Disable cache
Hope that shell work for you

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using "codepush".

I tried for two hours now to figure out why my Android version is always rolling back to the old code and doesn't show the new features.

The reason was an old CodePush which leads to downgrading the app.

Answer (score 0):

##### Try deleting the

- ./android/.idea folders.
- ./android/.gradle folders.

##### It works for me

[image]