# App loading from cache, not updating changes

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

Every time i make changes to my code, i have to do a 
`npm cache clean` 
to reflect the changes i made. Is there any permanent solution for this?

I already tried the solutions given in [React native run-android do not updating modified code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304116/react-native-run-android-do-not-updating-modified-code) , but still it is temporary.

I also have enabled hot reloading and live reloading as well. But even if i had not done it, it should update changes when reloaded manually.

My emulator is Nexus 5X, API version 28, memory 2048 MB.
react-native-cli version: 2.0.1
react-native version: 0.59.3.
I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and the RAM capacity is 8gb.

Comment: did you enabled hot reloading?

Comment: read this developer documentation link : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

Comment: @Vencovsky will it help?, as of me app caches on crash

Comment: @Vencovsky yes i did. But it does not update.

Comment: I was using VS code as my text editor. Then i switched to atom. Maybe the memory is overused. I'm not sure. But it worked fine for me on atom.

Answer (score 2):

In my case when I disable debugging then it updates. So this is my solution.

in Chrome dev tools > Network > Disable cache Hope that shell work for you

Comment: This worked when other options to hard refresh did not. Unchecking keeps the new files too.

Answer (score -2):

'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'

put this line in headers part.

Comment: which header? Can you explain it a bit, because i am new to react-native

Comment: in api headers part are available.

Comment: @RAVIPRAKASH its question on react-native, and your answer is far from topic. API is emulator soft version, app caches without any request made, where it could be added as well as no html though