# React Native does not consider new changes

Tags: android, react-native

When I change some code and then use react-native run-android, new changes do not appear in my application.

I search a little and found this code:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

but here is the thing: I see new changes, but I should do it every time. Is there any way to automate this process?

Comment: Possible duplicate to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304116/react-native-run-android-do-not-updating-modified-code there you can find tricks for workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run this command everytime you change code.Just change the code shake the device and enable hot reloading and enable live reload.This will reload app everytime you make changes to app.If you are using ios simulator press command+R it will open reload window.

Comment: this is the problem: I enabled these two options. but there is no change. when I want to reload manually, it says that  "Could not connect to development server."

Comment: Are you testing it on android device?If yes then on which android version.

Comment: Android emulator

Comment: Try to run:
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
on your command prompt and re-run your project after that.

Comment: still no change. I can not connect to development server

Comment: Let me know the android api level of emulator

Comment: the emulator android version is 8.1 and api level 27

Comment: Close all your current terminal and follow the link I have added in the answer.