# Enable hot reloading on the note 9 for use w/ expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, samsung-galaxy, hot-reload

Anybody know how to access the hardware menu on the note 9? I need to be able to turn on "Enable Hot Reloading" as seen in this picture...

[image: picture]

Comment: Is this related? [How to enable live reload in react native on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933287/how-to-enable-live-reload-in-react-native-on-android)

Comment: your question does not relate to programming.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko If the question [How to enable live reload in react native on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36933287/9431247) relates to programming, then why doesn't mine?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen No bc that answer is wrt enabling the feature on an emulator where as I am trying to do so on a physical phone.

Comment: because your one does not relate to react native. At least you didn't mention that

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I tagged it.

Comment: _"I am trying to do so on a physical phone."_ And it's mentioned several times that you should shake the device. For example: _"On Android shake the device or press hardware menu button [...]"_

Comment: Actually I added the `react-native` and `expo` tags. But anyway, you had "expo" in the title, so people familiar with the topic would have known what this is all about. For others it might still be a complete mystery. But exactly how detailed and "dumbed down" should a question be? That's something to be discussed in meta. (And probably has already been.)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I tried shaking the phone & holding each of the 3 buttons on the nav bar to no avail. Could you please try to help me instead of insisting that my question has already been answered?

Comment: You hadn't yet tried shaking the phone when I suggested that this is duplicate of the other one. :) And this still is the same question. The other one just doesn't answer it for you specifically for some reason. So, what might be different? Is it not your exact use case?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Actually, I had already tried all of those things before coming here; I used to run expo on a Galaxy s5 & would access this menu by holding the hardware menu button. The answer you referenced is from 2016; I am running One UI so the method of accessing the feature I want may have changed.

Comment: We didn't know that. Now we do. Of course you could edit the question and mention what you've tried and that the "old tricks" don't work anymore, so people will know what you've tried and are not too eager to close this as a duplicate. Hopefully someone will come up with an up-to-date solution.