# How to fork metro bundler and watch for changes?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I have forked metro bundler repository (https://facebook.github.io/metro) and I want to add some changes to the source code. I want to make changes and automatically have the code recompiled when I save a file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933287/how-to-enable-live-reload-in-react-native-on-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable live reload in react native on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933287/how-to-enable-live-reload-in-react-native-on-android)